# Ficheiro continua em uso por Java / Como fechar ligação ao ficheiro

Tags: java, javafx

Problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para demonstrar o problema:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class viewImageFX extends Application {
    private Group g;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Button btnOpen = new Button("Open");
        Button btnDelete = new Button("Delete");

        btnOpen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                g = createImagewithDetails();
                pane.setCenter(g);
            }
        });
        btnDelete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                g = null;
                Label lbl =  new Label("eliminado");
                pane.setCenter(lbl);
            }
        });        

        HBox menu = new HBox();
        menu.getChildren().addAll(btnOpen, btnDelete);


        pane.setBottom(menu);


        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Group createImagewithDetails() {
        ImageView img = new ImageView();
        Group group = new Group();
        final Image image;
        try {
            image = new Image(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\movie_play_red.png")), 150, 0, true, true);
            img.setImage(image);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problema no load da Imagem ");
            Logger.getLogger(viewImageFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        Label lblDescricao = new Label("asflsanfa asisoafgsang asiga");
        group.getChildren().addAll(img, lblDescricao);

        return group;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Como consigo forçar a que o ficheiro deixe de ser usado?
Não é suposto, se colocar o `Group` devolvido a `null` que a referencia ao ficheiro seja perdida e dessa forme o liberte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) para fechar o `InputStream`:

```
try (InputStream imagemStream = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\movie_play_red.png"))) {
    image = new Image(imagemStream, 150, 0, true, true);
    img.setImage(image);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Problema no load da Imagem ");
    Logger.getLogger(CloseImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}  catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Problema ao fechar a imagem ");
    Logger.getLogger(CloseImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve fechar o FileInputStream após o uso, tente fazer desta forma:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\movie_play_red.png"));
image = new Image(fis, 150, 0, true, true);
img.setImage(image);

// Adicione isso
fis.close();
```